# How to intercept a method of an existing class and delegate all calls to a different implementation of the interface using byte-buddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I am new to byte-buddy and I am trying to use the same for building a solution in my project. For a particular scenario, I am clueless how to implement the solution.

I have 2 implementations of an interface (or subclass of a parent class)

Based on a condition, I want to delegate all the Class1 method calls to Class2.

Example :

```java
public class Class1 implements SampleInterface{

public Map<String,String> operation1(List<String> var){
}

public void operation2(List<String> var){}

public void operation3(){
   System.out.println("Class1 :  Operation 3");
}
}
```

```java
public class Class2 implements SampleInterface{

public Map<String,String> operation1(List<String> var){
}

public void operation2(List<String> var){}

public void operation3(){
   System.out.println("Class1 : Operation 3");
}
}
```

I want to redefine the Class1 as below using byte-buddy.
I want to inject an instance of Class2 to Class1.
The condition clause needs to placed inside every method.

Can someone help with the answers ?

```java
public class Class1 implements SampleInterface{

Class2 proxyInstance;

public Map<String,String> operation1(List<String> var){
   if(condition==true){
      return proxyInstance.operation1(var);
   }else{
      //Class1 implementation
   }
}

public void operation2(List<String> var){
   if(condition==true){
      return proxyInstance.operation2(var);
   }else{
      //Class1 implementation
   }

}

public void operation3(){
   if(condition==true){
     proxyInstance.operation3();
   }else{
      System.out.println("Class1 :  Operation 3");
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Byte Buddy, you should be able to use `MethodDelegation` for this. You can get the original method by declaring a parameter `@Origin Method m` and the arguments by `@AllArguments Object[] args`. You can then use this to invoke the method on the delegate instance or dispatch your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

I could implement the solution the way I wanted to by mixing  javassit and byte-buddy. I could achieve the following things via this implementation

1. Do instrumentation without attaching -javaagent in the command line
2. I could include multiple agents under a single jar and call them as required from the main method.
3. I could change the behavior of a method and add new fields at the class level.

Though there hasn't been any response for my question, it was nice experience to learn various aspects of this topic and reaching to a point where I could implement the solution as requested